# extract COUNT(column) from mySQL to VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hey guys I have to extract some values from my DB and put them on my textbox. There's a problem at :

```
 TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & DR.Item("id") & Space(3) & DR.Item("Nume") & Space(3) & DR.Item("COUNT(pontaj.prezente)")
```

Error in VB:

[image: Error in VB]

This is how my select looks like:

[image]

```
 Dim dbCon = New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database = users; Uid=root; Pwd = password ")
        'SELECT users1.id,users1.Nume, COUNT(pontaj.prezente) FROM users1, pontaj WHERE users1.id = pontaj.id

        Dim strQuery = "SELECT users1.id,users1.Nume, COUNT(pontaj.prezente)" & _
            "FROM users1, pontaj "



        Dim SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)

        '  Pwd = password

        ' Open

        dbCon.Open()

        Dim DR = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & DR.Item("id") & Space(3) & DR.Item("Nume") & Space(3) & DR.Item("COUNT(pontaj.prezente)") & vbCrlf
        While DR.Read


        End While

        'Close

        DR.Close()
        dbCon.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error is clear, you cannot access the fields of a DataReader before calling Read.
The call is required to position the reader on the first record returned by the query and then to advance on the subsequent records until you reach the end of the returned records.

Also the syntax for your query seems incorrect and the way you reference the third column of your query

```
 Dim dbCon = New MySqlConnection(............)
 Dim strQuery = "SELECT users1.id,users1.Nume, COUNT(pontaj.prezente) as countPrezente " & _
                 "FROM users1 INNER JOIN pontaj ON users1.id = pontaj.id " & _
                 "GROUP BY users1.id, users1.Nume"
 Dim SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
 dbCon.Open()
 Dim DR = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader

 ' If Read returns true then you have one or more record to show'
 While DR.Read() 
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & _
                    DR.Item("id") & Space(3) & _ 
                    DR.Item("Nume") & Space(3) & _ 
                    DR.Item("countPrezente") & vbCrlf
 End While
 DR.Close
 dbCon.Close
```

Looking at your previous question, the Foreign Key between users1 and pontaj is named id, so I have used an explicit join between the two tables to link the records from the two tables